# Have a macro button that hides zero values - one row not being hidden

Tags: excel, vba

Running below "Code":

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$C$300").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<>0", Operator:=xlFilterValues

With Range("A3:P3")
.AutoFilter Field:=1, VisibleDropDown:=False
.AutoFilter Field:=2, VisibleDropDown:=False

End With
```

It works fine. Rows with a value of "0" in column C are hidden. However, when I place a zero in C2, the row is not hidden. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you please clarify `a zero value in column C on the second row` part? Do you mean that you are changing the value of cell `C2` to zero and you would expect the code to also hide row number 2?

Comment: That is correct Justyna. Thank you

Comment: Thanks for answering. By default `AutoFilter` is excluding Header row (in your case - row 2) from its execution. Would it work for you if you changed the range from `("$A$2:$C$300")` to `("$A$1:$C$300")`? Or do you have some data in Row 1? Is it possible for you to share a screenshot?

Comment: I tried changing the range to $A$1, however Row 2 is still not hidden despite having a "0" in C2.

Comment: If the 1st row is empty, then the macro won't work as expected. Try adding some headers to the 1st row before running the adjusting code. If the issue still occurs please paste a screenshot of your dataset.